# Product stock quantity in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, stock

Product stock quantity in Magento 1.9

If a customer check out the product.

Without payment The product stock quantity is -1 or in the current value.

Comment: without payment means cash on delivery ?

Comment: paypal payment to use

Comment: anything the customer add the product and with out payment the product is add the view cart page .. the product   quantity is -1  then payment is not done the customer the product is return to the the quantity or in the wishlist